# Method inexplicably continues after throwing an exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

The best explanation I have so far for this is "magic".

```
public string GetRouteSegmentData(RouteSegment RouteSegment, Exporter.RouteExporter Exporter)
{
    try
    {
        List<RouteProviderSegmentData> List = Provider.GetSegments(RouteSegment);         
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // logging and return null
    }
}

// -----------------
// In the Provider class (more accurately, a child of a Provider class)
public override List<RouteProviderSegmentData> GetSegments(RouteSegment RouteSegment)
{
    // CHECK 1
    if (RouteSegment.RouteLineEntity == null) { throw new Exception("LineEntity null for route " + RouteSegment.Code); }
    // CHECK 2
    if (RouteSegment.RouteLineEntity.ListRouteLineParts == null) { throw new Exception("LineParts null for route " + RouteSegment.Code); }  
    // ...
}
```

So this is what happens: CHECK 1 is true, RouteLineEntity is in fact null, and when I debug it nicely steps into the "throw" part. But then... nothing seems to happen with that. The catch in GetRouteSegmentData() doesn't catch anything, it's like nothing was ever thrown. GetSegments() simply continues on to CHECK 2, and since RouteLineEntity is still null, this throws an exception (because I'm trying to access the ListRouteLineParts property of an object that's null), and this time that exception DOES get caught in GetRouteSegmentData().

So for some reason my manually thrown exception is blatantly ignored.
I've tried to put some code behind that first thrown, but this is never executed (as you'd expect, I guess).

What's going on here?

Comment: Shouldn't your method be called like this `GetSegments(RouteSegment);` instead of `Provider.GetSegments(RouteSegment);`

Comment: Try chancing your break settings in VS, go to Debug -> Exceptions... then check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  This is break the debugger every time an exception is thrown, even if it is handled.  then see if your exception is actually being thrown.  It may be getting caught somewhere else

Comment: Sounds like multiple threads are involved. One with `RouteLineEntity` null and other with a valid instance.

Comment: Actually @NikhilAgrawal has a good point, you are calling GetSegments as if it were static, but it isn't

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make clear that these methods are in seperate classes. The GetSegments() method is part of a (child of a) Provider class. So the "Provider" in the first method is actually a public object, not a class.

Comment: There are no multiple threads either. At every moment, RouteLineEntity  is null.